# Determining if a linear equation system only has a specific solution given a condition.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have this exercise from the linear algebra course I'm currently taking. However I'm somewhat stuck.

**Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be real numbers. Show that the linear equation system
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2\\
    2 & 3\\
    3 & 4
  \end{pmatrix}x=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \alpha+2\beta\\
    \alpha+2\beta\\
    2\alpha+3\beta
  \end{pmatrix},
\end{equation*}
has solutions if and only if $\alpha+\beta=0$.**

Okay, so far I've been able to show, that if $\alpha+\beta=0$, then $\alpha=-\beta$, so the RHS can be written as

$$\begin{pmatrix}
    -\alpha\\
    -\alpha\\
    -\alpha
  \end{pmatrix}$$

I can indeed solve the equation when with gaussian elimination, but I'm not sure how I can show, that the system only has a solution, when $\alpha+\beta=0$. I could come with examples where where is no solution, but I'm unsure how to show it in general for all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can proceed with the Gaussian elimination keeping the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in place as variables. The result of the process gives you
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
0 & -1 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}x = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha + 2\beta \\
-\alpha - 2\beta \\
\alpha + \beta
\end{pmatrix}$$
This system clearly has solutions if and only if the last row on the right side is $0$, which is if and only if $\alpha + \beta = 0$.